# Text appears in one line if there is no space in it

Tags: css, sass, less

I have a `p` text which contains some text. Everything is working ok if this text contains spaces. But if there's no space text just appears in one line no matter how much text is written:
[dev tools screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sfjx.png)

[code screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH5ri.png)

I'm expecting text to split into multiple lines if it doesn't fit in only one.

I'm really out of ideas why it works this way. Here are computed styles:
[computed styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS8fd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is `overflow-wrap: break-word;`